# Python ffmpeg https

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg

I want to download a streaming video from a website using python and ffmpeg. I can download this video using the ffmpeg command in my shell but as soon as I try to use python ffmpeg i get this error:

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls or securetransport enabled.
```

Using this code:

```
ffmpeg.input(url).output("demo.mp4", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").overwrite_output().run()
```

How can I enable https support for python ffmpeg

If you need more information, let me know

Thank you in advance

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what needs to be done. If you aren't comfortable compiling it from the source, the [John van Sickle's builds](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) are compiled with libgnutls.

Comment: A workaround could be to call the shell to execute the ffmpeg command. It all depends on what you plan to do with the file and your program. It might not be suitable for your implementation, but maybe using os.system("Your command here") is enough?